# Jackson trying to convert json to Product class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert following json:

```
 [
  {
    "title": "1411635467882",
    "price": {
      "value": "1234",
      "currency": "INR"
    }
  }
]
```

to object of `List` of:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/content/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/content/model/Product.html

Using code:

```
final JavaType type = this.objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Product.class);
return this.objectMapper.readValue(new File(filePath), type);
```

Which gives following error:

```
Can not set com.google.api.services.content.model.Price field com.google.api.services.content.model.Product.price to java.util.LinkedHashMap (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.content.model.Product["price"])
```

If I replace Product and Price class with simple pojo classes. It works fine but it doesn't work for product class given by third party located at:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/content/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/content/model/Product.html

Comment: Using [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-shopping/v1-rev53-1.14.1-beta) version of the google library, your code works fine for me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am using v2-rev53-1.20.0 google-api-services-content.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am also facing another problem with their given class and jackson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327347/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-of-google-product-object

Comment: @VivekGoel I have the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @zt1983811 No, Just for patch,  After deserialize I just call getUnknownKeys() and then calling remove for each key Elements.

Comment: @VivekGoel Should we post this problem to somewhere for Google to fix it?

Comment: @VivekGoel you know where to do it ?